# Adding Facebook "like" feature per list item

Tags: html

I wanted to know if it is possible To add the Facebook "like" feature per ul list item?

Comment: Is there *any* supporting information? HTML mark-up, what you've already tried, what went wrong..? ***Anything at all?***

Comment: I have a <ul> list containing images (img src is a thumbnail and a href is a link to a full image) that populate itself automatically with a php script and I wanted to know if it was possible to add a "like" button below every thumbnail in my list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can generate a like code here:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Comment: yeah that's the like button i want below every thumbnail.

Comment: you want it automatically generated?

Comment: yes.

thats the script i have:

$type = 'c';

$imagesDir = 'images/';

$images = glob($imagesDir . $type . '*[TYPE].{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE);

<ul>
<?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo str_replace('[TYPE]', 'F', $image); ?>"><img src="<?php echo str_replace('[TYPE]', 'T', $image); ?></a>" alt="" /></li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>

I wanted to know how I can add a "Like" button for every image loaded into this list. sorry it is a little bit messy I can't break a line here..

Comment: could you not just have <iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=<?php echo str_replace('[TYPE]', 'F', $image); ?>...</iframe>